# Main to Sub to oven w/ detours

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I have owned the house I’m living in for 20 years. There’s a subpanel in the back yard where a spa used to sit. It is fed by a 50-amp breaker in the main service. I got rid of the spa and I built a water feature. Also I ran a 4 wire to the house at around 55 feet in a conduit to power a 30-amp oven. The sub panel has one 50-amp breaker and two 20-amp breakers. On one 20 –amp breaker I have a short run to a GFI receptacle to power the pump. The other 20 amp used to feed a switch for flood lights but I switched it out and added another GFI receptacle for a sub pump and a filter.

Up until a few weeks ago it ran like a champ. My oven is pretty old and was having issues before I added the additional GFI for the filter. I believe that my oven is in need of repair. It runs and then goes dead and when it does it trips one of the GFI receptacles but not both and not the 50-amp breaker. Its Always the same one. Today I started swapping out wire connectors and tightening ground wires. I changed the 20-amp breaker and reset the works from the main service. It worked for 10 minutes or so and I was back to square one. I think the oven is the problem, I can’t see any other reason other than I might be using more power than I have to run the new sub-pump and filter. Any ideas why only that 20-amp breaker is tripping? Thanks, I hope this is understandable.

Comment: What make and model is said subpanel? Also, can you post photos of its innards please?

Comment: What is a sub pump? Or is this just a pump off the sub panel? You also stated new sub pump, when troubleshooting and there was a recent change I go there first.

Comment: Be careful. If the oven has a 3-wire connection, there's a fair chance the chassis of the oven is energized!